# Make "text-scale-increase" increase font by one?

Tags: fonts

Currently for me "text-scale-increase" and "C-X X-+" increase the font size by very high number- so it is either super big, or super tiny. How do I make it to increase it by 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the help for `text-scale-increase` with the key combo `C-h f text-scale-increase <RET>`. This will show you the following:

> Each step scales the height of the default face by the variable
>   `‘text-scale-mode-step’` (a negative number of steps decreases the
>   height by the same amount).  As a special case, an argument of 0
>   will remove any scaling currently active.

So you can modify the size of the steps by customizing `text-scale-mode-step`, via `M-x customize-variable text-scale-mode-step <RET>`. The default value is 1.2, so anything smaller (e.g., 1.1) will result in smaller increments.

Note that this is a multiplication factor, not a discrete font size difference. That is, you are increasing your font by 1.2 times, not by 2 point sizes. Since fonts come in discrete sizes, small changes in `text-mode-scale-step` may cause the same actual change. For my system, only the first decimal place is useful -- 1.05 and 1.06 produce identical increments.

Answer (score 2):

To supplement what @Tyler said, there is also variable, but not option, `text-scale-mode-amount`.

`C-h f text-scale-mode`:

> **`text-scale-mode`** is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
>   `face-remap.el`.
>
> `(text-scale-mode &optional ARG)`
>
> Minor mode for displaying buffer text in a larger/smaller font.
>
> With a prefix argument `ARG`, enable the mode if `ARG` is positive,
>   and disable it otherwise.  If called from Lisp, enable the mode
>   if `ARG` is omitted or `nil`.
>
> The amount of scaling is determined by the variable
>   **`text-scale-mode-amount`**: one step scales the global default
>   face size by the value of the variable `text-scale-mode-step`
>   (a negative amount shrinks the text).
>
> The `text-scale-increase`, `text-scale-decrease`, and
>   `text-scale-set` functions may be used to interactively modify
>   the variable **`text-scale-mode-amount`** (they also enable or
>   disable `text-scale-mode` as necessary).

As the doc says, you can modify variable **`text-scale-mode-amount`** interactively.  It is not a user option.